# Create a navbar adaptable to small screens in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, navbar

I'm creating a navbar for my site and I want make it adaptable to small screens. For this, when I reduce the screen, all the navbar options collapse into a striped icon. My problem is how can I make this icon clickable for showing all navbar options using TypeScript.

This is what I tried to do:

In CSS code I wrote some classes for graphics effects:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .max-width {
        padding: 0 50px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 947px) {
    .menu-btn {
        display: block;
        z-index: 999;
    }  

    .menu-btn i.active::before {
        content: "\f00d"; /* Crocetta... */
    }

    .navbar .menu {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        left: -100%;
        top: 0;
        background: #111;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 80px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .navbar .menu.active {
        left: 0;
    }

    .navbar .menu li {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar .menu li a {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 20px 0;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
```

In my TypeScritp file I tried to generate a method for active/disable an ".active" class:

```
export class MenuComponent {

  public cambiaColore: boolean = false;
  public menuActive: boolean = false;

  constructor(@Inject (DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  @HostListener('window:scroll')
  onWindowScroll() {

    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      this.cambiaColore = true;
    } else {
      this.cambiaColore = false;
    }

  }

  //TODO: Comprendere come addattarlo al cellulare!
  toggleMenu() {
    this.menuActive = !this.menuActive;
  }
  
}
```

And in my HTML file I tried to call this method and add to nav tag an "active" class like this:

```
<nav [class.addColor]="cambiaColore" [class.active]="menuActive" class="navbar">
    <div class="max-width">
        <div class="logo"><a href="#">Nucleo Mobile <span>Varese</span></a></div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">In generale</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">La nostra missione</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cosa facciamo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dove siamo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Comun`your text`i</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <i class="fas fa-bars" (click)="toggleMenu()"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But it doesn't work. I'm not understanding why. Can someone help me please?
It's based on this JQuery code:

```
$(".menu-btn').click(function() {
    $('.navbar .menu').toggleclass("active");
    $('.menu-btn i').toggleclass("active");
});
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: From your code, it looks like you are using Bootstrap.  I think what is happening is what I talk about below: JQuery changes the class, then Angular changes it back.  If you use the databinding approach detailed in my answer, this won't happen.

Comment: Thank You for response. Like I responsed to next answer: I think I'm wasn't clear. The JQuery that I posted is the code that I use for took a cue for my TS code. I don't use JQuery for an Angular Project but I want to know how should I write the code to obtain  the same result as the code in JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use jQuery with Angular, at least not to manipulate the DOM.  The reason is that Angular also modifies the DOM, and with jQuery, you can run into race conditions. JQ might change it one way, then Angular will change it right back.

In fact, you should really avoid manipulating the DOM at all.  Instead use data binding.  Something like:

```js
public isMyMenuActive: boolean = false;

public toggleMenu(): void {
    this.isMyMenuActive = !this.isMyMenuActive;
}
```

```html
<div class="X" [ngClass]="{'active': isMyMenuActive}"
```

Secondly, you may want to checkout bootstrap, ng-bootstrap, Angular Material etc.  They have menus that work like this out of the box.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank You for response. I think I'm wans't clear: the code in JQuery posted in my question is that I found in the internet tutorial and I don't use it in my project, but I just took a cue from it for my TS code. Now, my question is in wich tags I must put the [class.active]="this.menuActive" in the HTML file ? And what is the difference between [class.nameClass]="" and [ngClass]="". Thanks for help !

Comment: Your markup is missing several elements of a Bootstrap navbar.  That's why it's not working.  You should go through the examples in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/.

Comment: Functionally, [class.active]="expression" and [ngClass]="{'active': expression}" are the same.  The only difference is that you can add several classes at the same time using ngClass by separating the expressions with commas, e.g. [ngClass]="{'active': expression, 'highlighted': otherExpression}"

Comment: Ok, thank You. You're really help me. Another question, if I can. The button for reduce the navbar,  (<div class="menu-btn">) is from this library: kit.awesome. Can that also influence the functioning, or is it just bootstrap that is missing... ? Thanks.